# Simulate mouse click/scroll/etc on swing without using Robot

Tags: java, swing

I want to simulate basic input for a swing application. The whole thing runs headless and doesn't even have a JFrame. I just render all components from the JPanel using the draw() method on a Image (If you want to know why: The Image gets rendered on minecraft maps where users then should be able to interact). I want to execute click or scroll actions on the panel like it would come from regular user.

I know that I can simulate a Button click using doClick() but this doesn't work for components like checkboxes. I also tried using dispatchEvent() but that didn't fire the animations or on some components even threw a HeadlessException.

Comment: Maybe you could post a [mcve]? Maybe you can post the stack trace of the `HeadlessException`? Did you try method [setSelected](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.desktop/javax/swing/AbstractButton.html#setSelected(boolean))?

Comment: _Button click using doClick() but this doesn't work for components like checkboxes_ that's wrong - there certainly are components that do not have programmatic api to simulate interactions, all button types are not among them ;)

Comment: as to the problem: there are types of interactions that can't be simulated in a headless environment - afaik you either have to test those in a real ui context or skip them.

Comment: a quick search came up with several QAs here on SO: java+swing+test+ui+headless - maybe some of them helps you to move on :)